# Install to computer using flash drive

Tags: system-installation

I have an Acer notebook computer loaded with Windows 7 Home Starter.  It will no longer recognize my boot up password.  I would like to trash it and install Ubuntu.  The problem is I only have a USB drive and no CD drive. I do not want to  have to use a flash drive each time I boot the computer.  How can I download and install with a memory stick. (USB flash)
thanks

Comment: Just download an installation image, write to your flash drive, then boot from it and install. Directions are at ubuntu.com.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty simple. Find another usable PC and follow the steps. First you'll have to download the Ubuntu (or one of its flavors) ISO image from [ubuntu.com/download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download). If you are using Windows 7, download the program UNetBootIn ([unetbootin.sourceforge.net](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net)). This program allows you to make a bootable flash drive with Ubuntu ISO. Follow the steps of the program.

After you're done, plug your USB stick and restart your PC. When you see your BIOS, you have to enter its Boot Device Selection Menu (usually pressing Del, F2, F10 or F12). Select your USB and Ubuntu Live will boot. You can install Ubuntu on your PC from there.

Comment: I would not recomend unetbootin. It spoils partition table frequently.

Comment: I do not think this is a great problem.